# Safari - HTML5 Audio

Tags: html, audio, safari

I'm using javascript to dynamically populate the audio tag with source info. Works fine in Chrome, but in Safari the source info changes within the audio tag and yet it plays the same song. Any ideas as to why this would be happening?

http://www.chicagowebguru.com/HTML5Player/

Answer (score 3):

In Safari, when you change the source, you also have to call `.load()` on the audio player to get it to actually load the new source.

Other browsers don't need this it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried recreating the node?

```
document.removeChild(document.getElementById("audio-player");

var dynamicAudio = document.createElement("audio");
dynamicAudio.name = "audio-player";
dynamicAudio.id = "audio-player";
var dynamicSound1 = document.createElement("source");
var dynamicSound2 = document.createElement("source");
var dynamicSound3 = document.createElement("source");
dynamicSound1.src = "http://www.chicagowebguru.com/audio/RainbowConnection.mp3";
dynamicSound2.src = "http://www.chicagowebguru.com/audio/RainbowConnection.ogg";
dynamicSound3.src = "http://www.chicagowebguru.com/audio/RainbowConnection.wav";
dynamicAudio.appendChild(dynamicSound1);
dynamicAudio.appendChild(dynamicSound2);
dynamicAudio.appendChild(dynamicSound3);

refNode = document.getElementById("message-container");
document.body.insertBefore(dynamicAudio,refNode.nextSibling);
```

or you could use jQuery maybe